# set variance of gaussian function in opencv canny function

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement a research paper [click here to see paper](http://mile.ee.iisc.ernet.in/mile/publications/softCopy/DocumentAnalysis/CBDAR_Kasar_2007.pdf).

I am using opencv library to implement this.

According to paper, at a particular step, canny edge detection needs to be performed with thresholds 0.2 and 0.3 for the hysteresis thresholding step and variance of associated gaussian function is taken 1.

My question how can we set variance of gaussain function in opencv canny function?

Comment: Hello Vishal, i'd be interested to know how your opencv implementation worked out, the research paper looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

`Canny()` does not automatically calculate the `GaussianBlur()`---you need to do it as a preprocessing step. The function [`GaussianBlur()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur) takes in arguments for the standard deviation in each direction; you can set them to `1`.

Additionally [`Canny()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#canny) requires a `uint8`, not `float` image, so the thresholds should be `int(0.2*255) = 51` and `int(0.3*255) = 77` for your values, but note these often depend on your image so you may want to play around with them.